# PIC 18F252 config settings help

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming

I need to blink a simple LED with PIC18F 252 but I could not figure out the config settings for doing so.

I read the datasheet looking for internal oscillator, but I could not find it. I don't want to use an external oscillator. Can someone help me with simple config settings which is good enough to set the port B to high or low with some delays?

I just need help with config settings. It would be better if config is provided in #pragma config Settings format. Out of the 8 available oscillators which one shall I use?

Also please help me to understand this code below:

```
__CONFIG(1, OSCSDIS & XT);
__CONFIG(2, BOREN & BORV42 & PWRTEN & WDTDIS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you read the datasheet, but you clearly need to read it again.  Nowhere does it say that the 18F252 has a internal oscillator.

Try the 18F2520 instead.  It's the next version of the 18F252 but does have a internal oscillator.

Comment: Alright , agreed it does not have an internal oscillator.My question might have appreared Stupid but I am a beginner :). I did noticed that in first place that It does not have int Oscillator, but since i am a beginner so i was thinking there might be some way around. Anyway. Thanks. But If I were to add an external oscillator then what would be the config and what MHz oscillator shall i connect to the microcontroller ?

Comment: @Sanju: " what would be the config and what MHz oscillator shall i connect" - The datasheet for whatever chip you buy will have a section that explains exactly that